# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{a^n}, a > 0$

Tags: calculus

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{a^n}, a > 0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{a^n} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{a^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\log(\frac{n}{a^n})}$

Then what? $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(\frac{n}{a^n}) = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$

I am trying to use L'hopital's here but not sure how to do so. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: For $a=1/2$ you have $a^n\to 0$. What is about other values of $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at cases here: If $0<a\leq 1$, and if $a>1$. In the former, $0<a\leq1$ implies that $0<a^n \leq 1$, so that the limit 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{a^n} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} n
$$
and hence clearly diverges. If $a>1$, then $a = 1 + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$, and so you should be able to show that $\frac{n}{(1+\epsilon)^n} \to 0$ as
$$
\frac{n}{a^n}
= \frac{n}{(1+\epsilon)^n}
= \frac{n}{ 1 + n\epsilon + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2 + \cdots + \epsilon^n} \text{ by the binomial theorem.}
$$ 
Hence,
$$
0\leq
\frac{n}{a^n}
= \frac{n}{ 1 + n\epsilon + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2 + \cdots + \epsilon^n} 
\leq \frac{n}{ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2 } 
= \frac{2}{\epsilon^2} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1}
\to 0.
$$

Comment: So, there is no other simpler way to approach this?

Comment: This way is rather simple - all that I have pointed out is that you have to account for the nonuniformity in $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n$, as for $a>0$ there are two distinct behaviours that the limit may take.

Comment: I will add a little more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was going to the wrong direction by introducing logarithm in this.

Comment: For $a\gt 1$, L'Hospital's Rule will work just fine. But the argument above is far more basic.

Comment: @Jellyfish I wasn't really thinking about it too much, but in your question, you said you wanted to do it with L'Hospitals - you can do that too. Just use the rule on the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{a^x}$, and use the differentiation rules on $a^x$ correctly. Oh, and as André pointed out, it will only work if $a>1$ (as otherwise the limit is not an indeterminate form).

Comment: Thanks! actually this was given as an exercise after we've finished L'hopital's.